# Cannot reach tag info under markedContentInfo

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, text, itext

I am trying to parse a pdf ([paper](https://europepmc.org/articles/pmc3561725?pdf=render)) and get text for each different section separately. With using itext 5.5.6 (I have also tried itext 7 but somehow for some pdfs it returns weird characters while itext 5 works perfectly...), I can easily get font types, sizes and colors. I also want to reach tag information found under markedcontentinfo which is private under TextRenderInfo through which I am planning to retain the text with **/P** tag and ignore **/Artifact**.

As mentioned here ([itext](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.13.3/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/MarkedContentInfo.html)), there is getTag to retrive the info I need, however that option is not available under the renderInfo (see the code below).

How can I reach that info?

```
    @Override
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {

        String text = renderInfo.getText();
        result.append(renderInfo.getText());

        String curFontName = renderInfo.getFont().getFullFontName()[0][3];

        Vector curBaseline = renderInfo.getBaseline().getStartPoint();
        Vector topRight = renderInfo.getAscentLine().getEndPoint();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(curBaseline.get(0), curBaseline.get(1), topRight.get(0), topRight.get(1));
        float curFontSize = rect.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution for iText 7. While there may be some bugs in iText 7 that are not present in iText 5 (because many parts of iText 7 were created from scratch or have been significantly reworked), chances that any bugs at all are fixed in iText 5 are close to 0 while iText 7 is an actively developed and maintained library. Hence I recommend that you use iText 7 and ask specific questions about the troubles you have to the community (or the paid support if you are an active customer).

Helper class:

```
private static class MyEventListener implements IEventListener {
    @Override
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if (type == EventType.RENDER_TEXT) {
            TextRenderInfo info = (TextRenderInfo) data;
            java.util.List<CanvasTag> tags = info.getCanvasTagHierarchy();
            System.out.println("Text: " + info.getText());
            System.out.println("Role: " + tags.get(0).getRole().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
        return new HashSet<EventType>(Arrays.asList(EventType.RENDER_TEXT));
    }
}
```

Main calling code:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("path/to/file.pdf"));

PdfCanvasProcessor processor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(new MyEventListener());
processor.processPageContent(pdfDocument.getPage(1));
```

Output for the first page of your document:

```
Text: Low macrophage accumulation in skeletal muscle of obese type 
Role: /P
Text: 2 diabetics and elderly subjects
Role: /P
Text: Charmaine S Tam, PhD
Role: /P
Text: , 
Role: /P
Text: Lauren M Sparks, PhD
Role: /P
Text: , 
Role: /P
Text: Darcy L Johannsen, PhD
Role: /P
Text: , 
Role: /P
Text: Jeffrey D 
Role: /P
Text: Covington, B.S
Role: /P
Text: , 
Role: /P
Text: Timothy S Church, PhD, MD
Role: /P
Text: , and 
Role: /P
Text: Eric Ravussin, PhD
Role: /P
Text: Pennington Biomedical Research Center, Baton Rouge, LA
Role: /P
Text: Abstract
Role: /P
Text: In addition to adipose tissue, recent studies suggest that skeletal muscle may also be a source of 
Role: /P
Text: low grade inflammation, particularly in inactive and/or overweight individuals. The aim of this 
Role: /P
Text: study was to examine the presence of macrophages in skeletal muscle from obese subjects with 
Role: /P
Text: type 2 diabetes (T2D) before and after a 9-month exercise program (vs. a non-exercising control 
Role: /P
Text: group) (Study 1) and in young vs. elderly subjects (Study 2). In both studies, CD68+ macrophages 
Role: /P
Text: in 
Role: /P
Text: vastus lateralis
Role: /P
Text:  biopsies were determined by immunohistochemistry and inflammation gene 
Role: /P
Text: expression measured. Macrophage content (%) was calculated by the number of macrophages per 
Role: /P
Text: 100 muscle fibers. In 
Role: /P
Text: Study 1
Role: /P
Text: , we found relatively low numbers (2–3%) of CD68+ macrophages in 
Role: /P
Text: skeletal muscle in obese T2D subjects (BMI= 37.3 ± 5.2kg/m
Role: /P
Text: 2
Role: /Span
Text: ), which were unchanged after a 9-
Role: /P
Text: month exercise program (P=0.42). Similarly, in 
Role: /P
Text: Study 2
Role: /P
Text:  (BMI=27.1 ± 2.5kg/m
Role: /P
Text: 2
Role: /Span
Text: ), CD68+ 
Role: /P
Text: macrophages were relatively low in muscle (4–5%) and were not different between young and 
Role: /P
Text: elderly individuals (P=0.42). However, elderly subjects had 2-fold higher CD68 and CD206 gene 
Role: /P
Text: expression (both P<0.002) than young participants. In both studies, CD68+ muscle macrophages 
Role: /P
Text: were not associated with BMI. In conclusion, we found little evidence of macrophage 
Role: /P
Text: accumulation in skeletal muscle in obese T2D subjects or in elderly individuals. A 9-month 
Role: /P
Text: exercise program was not associated with a decrease in macrophage content.
Role: /P
Text: Keywords
Role: /P
Text: macrophage; muscle; inflammation; obesity; type 2 diabetes
Role: /P
Text: Introduction
Role: /P
Text: Adipose tissue from obese humans and high-fat fed animal models is characterized by 
Role: /P
Text: significant immune cell accumulation. In particular, macrophages located in crown-like 
Role: /P
Text: structures secrete pro-inflammatory mediators into the circulation leading to a state of low-
Role: /P
Text: grade inflammation. Some studies suggest that macrophages also directly infiltrate skeletal 
Role: /P
Text: muscle, potentially further contributing to local and systemic inflammation in obesity (
Role: /P
Text: 1
Role: /Span
Text: –
Role: /P
Text: 5
Role: /Span
Text: ). 
Role: /P
Text: Users may view, print, copy, and download text and data-mine the content in such documents, for the purposes of academic research, 
Role: /P
Text: subject always to the full Conditions of use:
Role: /P
Text: http://www.nature.com/authors/editorial_policies/license.html#terms
Role: /Link
Text: Corresponding author and reprint requests to:
Role: /P
Text:  Eric Ravussin, Pennington Biomedical Research Center, 6400 Perkins Road, Baton 
Role: /P
Text: Rouge, LA, USA, 70808, Phone: 225-763-3186, Fax: 225-763-3030, eric.ravussin@pbrc.edu. 
Role: /P
Text: Disclosure:
Role: /P
Text:  The authors have no conflicts of interest and nothing to disclose
Role: /P
Text: HHS Public Access
Role: /Artifact
Text: Author manuscript
Role: /Artifact
Text: Obesity (Silver Spring)
Role: /Artifact
Text: . Author manuscript; available in PMC 2013 February 01.
Role: /Artifact
Text: Published in final edited form as:
Role: /Artifact
Text: Obesity (Silver Spring)
Role: /Artifact
Text: . 2012 July ; 20(7): 1530–1533. doi:10.1038/oby.2012.24.
Role: /Artifact
Text: Author Manuscript
Role: /Artifact
Text: Author Manuscript
Role: /Artifact
Text: Author Manuscript
Role: /Artifact
Text: Author Manuscript
Role: /Artifact
```